# Disabled Firefox Add-on ActionButton not grayed out

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

When creating a Firefox Add-on `ActionButton` `disabled`, e.g.,

```
var button = new ActionButton({
  id: 'my-link',
  label: 'My label',
  icon: {
    '16': './icon-16.png',
    '32': './icon-32.png',
    '64': './icon-64.png'
  },
  onClick: handleClick,
  disabled: true
});
```

the button indeed isn't clickable and doesn't produce any events, but the icon does *not* appear grayed out as advertised in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action).

Any ideas as to why this might be?

Comment: Nice catch. This should be reported as a bug as on documentation it shows disabled icon has some opacity like 50%.

Comment: It's reported now. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1167559

Comment: Thanks @Nico :) Until they fix it though, you can use the style registration i posted below

Answer (score 1):

Try this, the id of my button was `toggle-button--helloname-my-button1` where `helloname` is the name of my addon and `my-button1` was the id i set. So the dom id was `toggle-button--helloname-my-button1` you should update this to be `toggle-button--YOUR_ADDON_NAME-my-link`:

```
// globals
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
var sss = Cc['@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIStyleSheetService);

var cssUri;
var svgFilterUrl;
// end globals

if (Services.vc.compare(Services.appinfo.version, 34) < 0) {
    // for less then firefox v34
    if (!svgFilterUrl) {
        Cu.importGlobalProperties(['URL']);
        var oFileBody = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><filter id="grayscale"><feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0"/></filter></svg>';
        var {Blob} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm", {});
        var oBlob = Blob([oFileBody], {
            type: "text/xml"
        });
        svgFilterUrl = URL.createObjectURL(oBlob);
        console.log(url)
    }
    var css = '#toggle-button--helloname-my-button1[disabled] { filter: url(' + url + '#grayscale); }';
} else {
    // for less then firefox >= v34
    var css = '#toggle-button--helloname-my-button1[disabled] { filter:grayscale(1) }';
}
var newURIParam = {
    aURL: 'data:text/css,' + encodeURIComponent(css),
    aOriginCharset: null,
    aBaseURI: null
};
var cssUri = Services.io.newURI(newURIParam.aURL, newURIParam.aOriginCharset, newURIParam.aBaseURI);
sss.loadAndRegisterSheet(cssUri, sss.AUTHOR_SHEET);
```

and when you want to uninstall/disable your addon do `sss.unregisterSheet(cssUri, sss.AUTHOR_SHEET);`